# How to enable timestamp in Hive

Tags: hadoop, timestamp, hive, cloudera, create-table

After logging in to hive I get the following.

```
sudo -u hdfs hive
[warnings and information about deprecated configurations]
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.12.0-cdh5.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
```

When I create a table in Hive with a *timestamp* data type I get the following.

```
hive> create table rts(usergender string, usercity string, usersentiment int, zipcode string, sku string, createdat timestamp, category string, price float, county string, countycode string, userstate string, categorygroup string) partitioned by (createdat_hour bigint) stored as parquet;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: timestamp not implemented yet
```

Comment: And the solution was....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive timestamp is available after Hive 0.8 version.

Looks like you are using CDH 5 which comes with above Hive 0.10 . I don't see any kind of problems other than version type. Check your Hive version once.